# Compilação de kernel

Tags: sistema-operacional

Estou querendo compilar um kernel de um sistema operacional meu no Visual Studio. Como faço para linkar o bootloader em Assembly e o kernel em C?

Comment: Acredito que [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/668808/3517631) é o que você está procurando.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Sua pergunta não está clara. kernel de que?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Creio que seja um kernel de um sistema operacional, a julgar pela tag e pelo fato de o OP ter citado "bootloader" no texto da pergunta.